# Why isn't my anchor tag smooth scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html

I have added this in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

This is the link that navigates to the 'id="fillerSix"' div tag.

```
<h1><a href="#fillerSix">Mohammad Usman Khan</a></h1>
```

This is id="fillerSix" which the link should and does navigate to.

```
<div id="fillerSix" class="fillerSix">
```

This is my index.js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The link works, in that it directs the user to the anchor but there is no smooth scrolling.

Comment: Stupid questions first: is jQuery library embedded on the page? (because your example is working here: https://jsfiddle.net/vtxfqdw7/)

Comment: Is that code inside of a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: need  to preventDefault and then set hash in url yourself

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/qd7b15c5/1/

Comment: @PatrickMoore Yes I have this `<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` in the head tags of my html file.

Comment: @Mohammad then your block in `index.js` should probably be wrapped in `$(document).ready( function(){  /* your code here */ });` as indicated by DanielD above. Likewise you do NOT need `<script></script>` tags inside of a `.js` file

Comment: I had `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
` commented out...

Comment: do you actually have `<script type="text/javascript">` in your .js file? that would throw and none of the js will execute. The anchors will still work normally but none of your scrolling will be applied

Comment: @rlemon No, I have removed it and it is working fine. The CDN reference is sufficient.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the CDN. you said "my index.js file looks like this" and have `<script type="text/javascript">` in that file? you don't add script tags to .js files. you use script tags to include them.

Comment: @rlemon No. As a I mention in the comment above, it was in the head of the .html file, not the .js file.

Comment: yes, you said that about the jQuery file... in your post you show the contents of your index.js file. if they are actually the contents of said file nothing will work.

Answer (score 2):

Your block in `index.js` should probably be wrapped in `$(document).ready( function(){  /* your code here */ });` as indicated by DanielD above.

Likewise you do NOT need `<script></script>` tags inside of a `.js` file. This will lead to a parse error.

New contents of `index.js`:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
               if (target.length) {
                 $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Dang beat me to it! I tested this in a quick little sublime example and without the `$(document).ready() {}` and my click function to animate the body and html did NOT work. So it looks like that's it =) Edit: I'll toss you a +1 as soon as my daily vote cap resets.